# firebase auth does not work with Fi Phone number in usa

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, sms

I followed all steps for [Firebase Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) , The simple sign on app works fine with phone numbers that are **non** [Google fi service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fi) . But when tried on a device that have Google Fi service then verification SMS does not arrive.

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same issue. We reached out to Google Fi and then made us go through all the typical tests to see if we can receive from other short code phone numbers and to do the HELP message. All of it worked fine. We have opened a support ticket with Firebase and still waiting to hear back.

Comment: Update - Firebase support got back to us with a sample link to try as part of that troubleshooting. When we tried the link, it worked for our Fi numbers. Then our application also started working.

Comment: can you please two things, 1: generalized link that Firebase support send to you ( remove your app specific parts and replace them with uppercase like: PROJECT_NAME etc). 2: how to open support ticket

Comment: The sample app was not specific to our project, just some sample app that Firebase uses to rule out implementation issues. Sample app - https://sample-auth-c8ce0.web.app/phone-visible.html. As far as opening a support ticket, there is a Support link at the bottom of the Firebase console page. On the support page, you can choose specific products (Auth) and sub category SMS, eventually you will get to a form where you can fill out the details and submit. It takes a while for them to get back 2 - 3 days. Hope this helps.